# Store procedures for delete a repeat records

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

Hello i have a table in MySQL:

"contracts" where i create a 3 record's for each client_id, but one bug in the backend create more records on some client_id i try create a store procedure to delete repeat records, example for 3 records:

```
ID cliente_id amount_preapprove
1     1        10000
2     1        12000
3     1        14000
4     1        10000 // <- record repeat 
5     1        10000 // <- record repeat 
6     1        14000 // <- record repeat 
7     2        7000 
8     2        8000 
9     2        9000 
10    2        7000 // <- record repeat for client_id 2
11    2        8000 // <- record repeat 
12    2        9000 // <- record repeat 
... N Clients repeat
```

i need get distinc amount_preapprove for each user, truncate the table and insert result in the store procedures?

I only need a 3 records for each client

[image]

Comment: What is your server version? I don't think you need a stored procedure for that.

Comment: helo @PaulSpiegel thanks, i add a picture in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am unsure whether you really want to retain 3 records per client. In your sample data, it looks more like you are trying to delete duplicates on `(cliente_id, amount_preapprove)`.

If so, you could use the following query:

```
delete t
from mytable t
inner join mytable t1 
    on  t1.cliente_id = t.client_id
    and t1.amount_preapprove = t.amount_preapprove
    and t1.id < t.id
```

This query will delete every record for which another record exists with the same `cliente_id` and `amount_preapprove` but a smaller `id`. In other words, this deletes duplicates while retaining the record that has the smallest id.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by client_id order by id) as seqnum
      from t
    ) t
where seqnum <= 3;
```

You can also use a scalar comparison:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.seqnum <= any (select t2.seqnum
                       from t t2
                       where t2.client_id = t.client_id
                       order by t2.seqnum
                       limit 1 offset 2
                      );
```

The `any` is so the query returns all rows when there are fewer than three per client.

Comment: Hello thanks, i need a get all record's more than 3 from table "contracts" to pass a delete repeat records and only reinsert 3 on the table after truncate

Answer (score 0):

The following query will keep the first three rows (sorted by ID) per `client_id` and delete anything else:

```
delete t
from my_table t
join (
  select t1.ID
  from my_table t1
  where t1.ID > (
    select t2.ID
    from my_table t2
    where t2.cliente_id = t1.cliente_id
    limit 1
    offset 2
  )
) x using(ID);
```

After that operation the data will be:

```
| ID  | cliente_id | amount_preapprove |
| --- | ---------- | ----------------- |
| 1   | 1          | 10000             |
| 2   | 1          | 12000             |
| 3   | 1          | 14000             |
| 7   | 2          | 7000              |
| 8   | 2          | 8000              |
| 9   | 2          | 9000              |
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sJKWQuCzEFx2K8LbS6XBMa/0)

In MySQL 8 it would be a bit simpler using a CTE and `ROW_NUMBER()` window function:

```
with cte as (
  select ID, row_number() over (partition by cliente_id order by ID) as rn
  from my_table
)
delete t
from my_table t
join cte using(ID)
where rn > 3;
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kYMrwAgFyFm93mWJSX1tVj/0)